# multiple repositories sharing same context calling savechanges operation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

I have a Web API architecture in following way:

Controller -> Services -> Repositories

Dependency is injected into using `Unity` framework via constructor injection pattern.

i have something similar in my project:

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    private readonly IOrderRepo _orderRepo;
    private readonly IProductRepo _prodRepo;

    public OrderService(IOrderRepo orderRepo, IProductRepo prodRepo)
    {
        _orderRepo = orderRepo;
        _prodRepo = prodRepo;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _orderRepo.Update();
        _prodRepo.Insert();
    }
}

public class OrderRepo : IOrderRepo
{
    private readonly CreditPortalContext _context;

    public OrderRepo(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        //Do something
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class ProductRepo : IProductRepo
{
    private readonly CreditPortalContext _context;

    public ProductRepo(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Insert()
    {
        //Do something
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now, `OrderService` is calling two different repository method to perform some database operation.

What I want is if something fails in `_prodRepo.Insert();` method, it should rollback `_orderRepo.Update();` call as well.

I am too far in this project so can not perform major architecture change at this point. Also, the `context` object is getting instantiated only once.(using Unity `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`)

Is there anyway i can achieve this?

Comment: The problem is that you call `SaveChanges` inside the repo.  You need to treat the `DbContext` as a unit of work who's scope is controlled *outside* the repo.

Comment: With your current code, I think the easiest way to do that is to remove the calls to `SaveChanges` from the repos, and inject the `DbContext` in to your service also.  That way it's your service that can commit the operations with `SaveChanges` when it is ready.  If you want to restrict access to the `DbContext` from the service, you can inject a wrapper around it instead, that only exposes a method that calls `SaveChanges`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Any code sample specifying restricted access to `DbContext` from the service? Thanks!

Comment: I would just use a simple class that has the actual `DbContext` injected in to it, and stores it in a private field.Give that class a `SaveChanges` method that just forwards the call to the private context's `DbContext.SaveChanges` method.  Now inject your "wrapper" class in to the service.  It'll get the same context instance as the repos, and the only thing you will be able to call on it is `SaveChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

this is not an ideal situation at all and I am afraid you're going to have to be quite creative.

You can't really rollback a statement that has already been committed, but you can do something else else.

So the situation is like this : you have 2 calls, call A and call B.

call A commits successfully. call B fails and you want to rollback A.

My suggestion is to perform the first commit to a different table.

Create a copy of your table in the database and commit your data there. if B succeeds then you issue another command to transfer the data to the main table where it should be. If B fails then you simply remove the data from the second table and your main table remains untouched.

This can be done via a stored procedure maybe, that you can call, give it the id of the record and then it does an update on the main table using the row from the second table. You can easily call a stored procedure from entity framework so that part should not be a problem.

So bottom line, use a temporary storage place and only move the data when your second call succeeds

Comment: It's not practical to replicate the table structure in the database for all operations. I am leaning more towards to the comment given by @BradleyUffner